# How to customize HeaderTemplate of ValidationSummary Silverlight control?

Tags: silverlight, validation, xaml, validationsummary

I'd like to customize **HeaderTemplate** of **ValidationSummary** control from **Silverlight Toolkit** and display localized Header. But I cant figure out how to display error counter right to header's text ...
Can anybody help me with this?

My current XAML code ...

```
<sdk:ValidationSummary Grid.Row="3">
<sdk:ValidationSummary.HeaderTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <Grid Background="Red">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <TextBlock UseLayoutRounding="False"
                       Foreground="White"
                       Text="Editing Errors:" />
            <TextBlock UseLayoutRounding="True"
                       Foreground="White"
                       FontWeight="Bold"
                       Text="{Binding DisplayedErrors.Count}"
                       Grid.Column="1" />
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
</sdk:ValidationSummary.HeaderTemplate>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are any of the items in your grid displaying in the header? Is it only the DisplayedErrors.Count you're missing?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, I'm missing only DisplayedErrors.Count! That's the problem!

Answer (score 0):

Remove "DisplayedErrors.Count" from the Text="{Binding DisplayedErrors.Count}" statement keeping only Text="{Binding}"